# socrata ny data service not taking $where?

Tags: socrata

https://health.data.ny.gov/resource/u4ud-w55t.json?hospital_county=Suffolk$limit=1

works but

https://health.data.ny.gov/resource/u4ud-w55t.json?$where=hospital_county=Suffolk

does not. Why is this ? since $limit is working why is that $where is not?

Answer (score 1):

When using the $where clause you must surround string values with quotes. So the correct query would be:
https://health.data.ny.gov/resource/u4ud-w55t.json?$where=hospital_county='Suffolk'